# Send .txt file or .zip file by Telegram API to Telegram bot by requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send a .txt file or .zip file by API to my Telegram bot, i coded for .txt file but i got error.

My code:

```
wifi_pass = open("C:\\Windows\\pic\\wifi-pass.txt" , 'rb')
url = ("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendDocument?chat_id="+chat_id+"&document="+wifi_pass)

payload_txt = {
    "UrlBox":url,
    "AgentList" : "Google Chrome",
    "VersionsList" : "HTTP/1.1",
    "MethodList" : "POST"
}
req = requests.post("https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx", payload_txt)
```

and i got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\.D U T Y\wifi - pass\debug.py", line 33, in <module>
    url = ("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendDocument?chat_id="+chat_id+"&document="+wifi_pass)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "_io.BufferedReader") to str
```

what API URL should use to send .txt or .zip file to bot

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and i got .txt file in telegram bot:

```
txt = open("C:\\Windows\\pic\\wifi-pass.txt" , 'rb')
url = ("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendDocument?chat_id="+chat_id)
url_txt = requests.post(url, files={'document': txt})

payload_txt = {
    "UrlBox":url_txt,
    "AgentList" : "Google Chrome",
    "VersionsList" : "HTTP/1.1",
    "MethodList" : "POST"
}
req = requests.post("https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx", payload_txt)
```